# He seemed oblivious to the crowds of photographers snapping away. (what's away here?)

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> He seemed oblivious to the crowds of photographers snapping away. (what's away here?)

Why do we need 'away' here and what does 'away' mean here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'snapping away' mean here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187968/what-does-snapping-away-mean-here) (see the second answer - it explains what "away" does)

Comment: In such contexts, ***away*** is an ***intensifier***. Consider Q: *"Can I ask a question?"*, A: *"**Ask away**!"*, where that "intensified, emphatic" reply has similar implications to, for example, ***By all means**!*, or ***Please feel free to ask me anything you want**!*